# Allow only specific domain access the app.

Tags: angularjs, laravel, dns

Sou :D .

I have a small app that will be displayed via  on the 3 locations. I need to check somehow where user is coming from, sou his previous address, and on that way allow access to the users only if they are coming from www.blabla.com etc. domain .
The apps backend is build in Laravel and frontend is Angularjs.

Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Try using HTTP_REFERER in .htaccess